# Android : How to make GET request using Retrofit without parameter?

Tags: android, get, retrofit2

I am calling an API to fetch countries list. The response is in `JSON` format having an array of objects. Then I need to populate the response into a spinner. So How can I send a get request without any @Query or parameter and then read the response?

My Json is in this format:

```
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "sortname": "AF",
        "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "sortname": "AL",
        "name": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "sortname": "DZ",
        "name": "Algeria"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "sortname": "AS",
        "name": "American Samoa"
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you use now?

Comment: first study about retrofit

Answer (score 2):

Create a GET Request like below in your ApiService interface:

```
@GET("url")
    Call<String> getCountries();
```

Just don't add any parameter in your call method if you don't wish to send any parameter.

It should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Reference : [android-working-with-retrofit-http-library](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Create a pojo class as below  :

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("sortname")
@Expose
private String sortname;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getSortname() {
return sortname;
}

public void setSortname(String sortname) {
this.sortname = sortname;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```